# What does l stand for in lvalue?

Tags: c++

I have always thought that l and r in lvalue and rvalue stand for "left" and "right". However, today, my teacher enlightened me that r is "reference", which startled me. As a result, I'm confused now because I have no idea what l in lvalue is.

Comment: This is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues

Comment: "left" and "right" were the original meaning coined by K&R. (This referred to left and right side of assignment.) In C++, this has shifted slightly as things got much more complicated... ;-)

Comment: hmm r in `rvalue` is not `reference` otherwise `rvalue reference` would be tautology

Comment: Just found out about lvalue and rvalue: _They were introduced by Christopher Strachey for CPL [Strachey,196?], the ancestor to BCPL. Dennis Ritchie used “lvalue” to describe C (e.g. see [K&R,1978]), but left out “rvalue”, considering “lvalue” and “not lvalue” sufficient._ in [www.stroustrup.com/terminology.pdf](http://www.stroustrup.com/terminology.pdf). (So, I was wrong with "coined by K&R" (completely).)

Comment: _However, today, my teacher enlightened me that r is "reference"_
Yeah, it's not enlightenment if they're wrong, and the 'r' does not stand for 'reference'.

Answer (score 0):

Old standards point towards them simply called being left and right values (of an assignment).

In C, L values were named "Locator values" as they point to a memory address.